# Is there any way to get the "center" channel having a stereo track?

Tags: daw

**Context:**

I am really beginner. I know about sample rates, bit depth, but practically never used any DAW. Now I've installed Audacity and Sonar.

**To give a real life example:**

I use Aebersold backing tracks. Bass pure left, drums pure center, piano pure right. I would like to render out the piano, and record my guitar track there.

The easy solution would be to split the stereo track to two mono tracks and take the left track. However I am not satisfied with this solution, because the drum level is somehow decreased, but more importantly the drum and the bass will share a mono track this way, which means wherever I will pan this track later they stuck together forever.

The ultimate goal I would like to achieve to having a bass left, drums center, but no piano.

**Theoretic question**

Is there any way to separate left, center, right to three separate tracks? (where those signals are *really* pure left, center, right with no echoes and center is real mono, with no phase difference fancies etc.)

If not, then end of story.

**Practical question**

If yes, then any practical help how to do this in Sonar will be appreciated.

Comment: The theoretical problem falls in the class of "blind signal separation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signal_separation

Comment: similar to http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/removing-human-voice-from-songs -- though this question is phrased a bit different in that it is about the stereo mix and not in terms of a specific instrument (which may or may not be uniquely assigned to a single stereo track).   Despite this difference, most of the issues/difficulties of this that problem apply to this one.

Comment: not putting this as an answer because I'm not sure, but backing track apps like iReal Pro may have versions of most of the Aebersold tracks, and in iReal you can select playback of the different instruments, as well as export to wav, so selecting different source material may be best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked (bold emphasis added):

> Is there any way to separate left, center, right to three separate tracks? (where those signals are *really* pure left, center, right with no echoes and center is real mono, with **no phase difference fancies** etc.)

Pretty much **no**. The only way to separate the drums from the rest would be by comparing the left and right channels and either selecting or rejecting the information that matches, and even though that's done all the time, there will always be artifacts (e.g., phase differences, etc.) on both the resulting bass and drum tracks.